# Multiplying Mat matrices using reshape, Mat type issue in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, matrix, reshape

I'm trying to implement color conversion from RGB-LMS and LMS-RGB back and using reshape for multiplication matrix, following answer from this question : [Fastest way to apply color matrix to RGB image using OpenCV 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167381/fastest-way-to-apply-color-matrix-to-rgb-image-using-opencv-3-0)

My ori Mat object is from an image with 3 channel (RGB), and I need to multiply them with matrix of 1 channel (lms), it seems like I have an issue with the matrix type. I've read [reshape docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-reshape) and questions related to this issue, like [Issues multiplying Mat matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562851/issues-multiplying-mat-matrices?rq=1), and I believe I have followed the instructions.

Here's my code : [**UPDATED** : Convert into flat image]

```
void test(const Mat &forreshape, Mat &output, Mat &pic, int rows, int cols)
{
    Mat lms(3, 3, CV_32FC3);
    Mat rgb(3, 3, CV_32FC3);
    Mat intolms(rows, cols, CV_32F);

    lms = (Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 1.4671, 0.1843, 0.0030,
                                3.8671, 27.1554, 3.4557,
                                4.1194, 45.5161 , 17.884 );
    /* switch the order of the matrix according to the BGR order of color on OpenCV */


    Mat transpose = (3, 3, CV_32F, lms).t();  // this will do transpose from matrix lms

    pic     = forreshape.reshape(1, rows*cols);
    Mat flatFloatImage;
    pic.convertTo(flatFloatImage, CV_32F);

    rgb         = flatFloatImag*transpose;
    output      = rgb.reshape(3, cols);
}
```

I define my Mat object, and I have converted it into float using convertTo

```
Mat ori = imread("ori.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
int rows = ori.rows;
int cols = ori.cols;

Mat forreshape;
ori.convertTo(forreshape, CV_32F);

Mat pic(rows, cols, CV_32FC3);
Mat output(rows, cols, CV_32FC3);
```

Error is :

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == B.type() && (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_64FC1 || type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_64FC2)) ,
```

so it's the type issue.

I tried to change all type into either 32FC3 of 32FC1, but doesn't seem to work. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need is to convert your input to a flat image and than multiply them

```
float lms [] = {1.4671, 0.1843, 0.0030,
                            3.8671, 27.1554, 3.4557,
                            4.1194, 45.5161 , 17.884};
Mat lmsMat(3, 3, CV_32F, lms );

Mat flatImage = ori.reshape(1, ori.rows * ori.cols);
Mat flatFloatImage;
flatImage.convertTo(flatFloatImage, CV_32F);
Mat mixedImage = flatFloatImage * lmsMat;
Mat output = mixedImage.reshape(3, imData.rows);
```

I might have messed up with lms matrix there, but I guess you will catch up from here.

Also see [3D matrix multiplication in opencv for RGB color mixing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677188/3d-matrix-multiplication-in-opencv-for-rgb-color-mixing)

EDIT:
Problem with distortion is that you got overflow after float to 8U conversion. This would do the trick:

```
rgb         = flatFloatImage*transpose;
rgb.convertTo(pic, CV_32S);
output      = pic.reshape(3, rows)
```

Output:
[image];

Also I'm not sure but quick google search gives me different matrix for LMS [see here](https://ssodelta.wordpress.com/tag/rgb-to-lms/). Also note that opencv stores colors in B-G-R format instead of RGB so change your mix mtraixes recordingly.

Comment: Hi, thanks ! I've updated my code and seen your recommended question. I think now I'm facing the same issue as him (image distortion), here's [my result](https://i.imgur.com/kF9GYvL.jpg) So I need to multiply my source image with the matrix lms (conversion RGB-LMS), then the result will be multiplied with transpose matrix of lms to get the original RGB back (LMS-RGB). Thst's why I need to use transpose. Any idea why the distortion ?

Comment: Hi, thanks ! Yes.. actually there are several different conversion matrices from RGB to LMS, according to which reference we choose. In my case, I'm referring to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.10662.pdf). Sure, I'm aware of the BGR order, that's why I switched the matrix rows. I can either convert my image into RGB and directly use the matrix or switch the matrix to match BGR order. And something must be really wrong with my code.. I can't get the image that I want, still try to figure out. But I know your answer is the best approach to this. Thanks a lot !!